# Bind a list returned from a LINQ query to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

I have a linq query something like this

```
var Query = from c in table
            where (some condition)
            select new {
            Name = c.Name,
            courses = // this returns a list,
            };
```

How do I bind this to gridview so that the result is like this

```
name1 course1
name1 course2
name1 course3
name2 course1
name2 course2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
gridview.DataSource = Query.ToList().Select(a => a.courses
             .Select(c => new { Name = a.Name, Course = c }))
             .SelectMany(p=>p).ToList();
gridview.DataBind();
```

If you want to return this list from method then create class as below

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
}
```

now you can return list as

```
public List<MyClass> MyMethod()
{
    var Query = from c in table
                where (some condition)
                select new {
                Name = c.Name,
                courses = // this returns a list,
                };

    return Query.ToList().Select(a => a.courses
            .Select(c => new MyClass{ Name = a.Name, Course = c }))
            .SelectMany(p=>p).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It isn't working. In that column it is displaying
     System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]

Comment: One thing more I would like to ask. This query is inside a function. What should be the return type of the function?